# Set CRS for Raster in QgsRasterLayer (pyqgis)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

in a QGIS python plugin I get some code that writes a `asc` file, this is the header of the final file:

```
NCOLS  20 
NROWS  15 
XLLCORNER  664400.000000 
YLLCORNER  4749500.000000 
CELLSIZE   100.000000  
NODATA_VALUE   -9999.0 
NODATA_VALUE   -9999.0
```

as you can see I get the X and Y corners of the file.

I wanted also to load the file in QGIS and obviously it asks me for the CRS.

What I am looking for, is to avoid this message and the related pop-up window while using `QgsRasterLayer`.

I've found this 2 old questions:

[How can I specify the CRS of a raster layer in pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27745/how-can-i-specify-the-crs-of-a-raster-layer-in-pyqgis)

and

[How to get CRS of a raster layer in pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57745/how-to-get-crs-of-a-raster-layer-in-pyqgis)

but I cannot use them in order to solve my problem.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: @AndreSilva. The second answer talks about a raster already loaded in the TOC and many answers in the first question talk about ``iface``..

Comment: Do you know which UTM (probable) zone or other CRS it is, and thus the EPSG well-known ID?

Comment: @mkennedy. Yes, I can retrieve the CRS (and EPSG code) easily.

Answer (score 6):

For example, if you can retrieve the CRS (and EPSG code) easily then you can assign CRS easily with a few paths at the Python Console of QGIS. For example, I load a raster (**xwRcl.tif**) where it also asks me for the CRS (see next image).

[image]

These commands at the Python Console do the work:

```
>>>layer = iface.activeLayer()
>>>CRS = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
>>>CRS
<qgis._core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem object at 0x9fbc5dac>
>>>CRS.createFromSrid(32612) #EPSG = 32612
True
>>>layer.setCrs(CRS)
>>>layer.crs().postgisSrid()  #to corroborate the assignation
32612L
```

I saved the raster with another name (**test_crs.tif**):

```
provider = layer.dataProvider()

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()

pipe.set(provider.clone())

rasterWriter = QgsRasterFileWriter("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_crs.tif")

xSize = provider.xSize()
ySize = provider.ySize()

rasterWriter.writeRaster(pipe, xSize, ySize, provider.extent(), CRS)
```

and after reloaded it, in this opportunity, it was avoided the message of asking me for the CRS.

Comment: Just a note that on QGIS 2.14 and 2.18, the line in your second code block that saves the raster- `pipe.set(provider.clone())` appears to crash QGIS. Saving of the raster, however, seems to work without that line so that's not a problem.